# How to represent "no flags" using enum.Flag?

Tags: python

I want to use an `enum.Flag` in a library function to allow users configuring multiple additive options.
Since some of these options are usually what users would want to do, there is a sensible default.
However it should still be possible to pass in a value to disable all options.

Reading up on `enum.Flag` and following the advice to ["use `auto` as the value and let `Flag` select an appropriate value"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#flag) I came up with something like this:

```py
import enum

class Foo(enum.Flag):
    NONE = enum.auto()
    BAR = enum.auto()
    BAZ = enum.auto()

def do_something(foo: Foo = Foo.BAR):
    pass
```

This works but when combining the `Foo.NONE` flag with say `Foo.BAR` I end up with `<Foo.BAR|NONE: 3>` while I'd want to end up with just `<Foo.BAR: 2>`.

I also tried not defining the `NONE` member at all but this requires users to pass in `Foo(0)` if they want to not specify any flags which is not obvious at all.

How do you define this class so that combining `Foo.NONE` and `Foo.BAR` ends up as `Foo.BAR` and users get to pass an obvious member to not set any of the flags?

Comment: There is actually example showing the thing you need in the very same link you provided.

Comment: @matszwecja Kind of, yes. But it focuses on the boolean value being `False` rather than explaining why an explicitly defined "no flags" member should be 0.

Answer (score 1):

To someone not used to how bit operations and flags work this might be a bit confusing.
To those who are `Foo.NONE | Foo.BAR` resulting in `<Foo.BAR|NONE: 3>` (note the `3`) is probably what gives it away.

So what is happening here?

> `enum.auto()` assigns appropriate values to enum members starting at 1 as explained in [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.auto):
>
> > Instances are replaced with an appropriate value for Enum members. By default, the initial value starts at 1.

> The other important bit to understand what's going on is mentioned in the [`Flag` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#flag)
>
> > Individual flags should have values that are powers of two (1, 2, 4, 8, …)

Thus, the example is equivalent to defining the members explicitly like this:

```py
import enum

class Foo(enum.Flag):
    NONE = 1
    BAR = 2
    BAZ = 4
```

The reason for this is more apparent when thinking about the values in binary representation: `Foo.NONE = 1 = 0b001`, `Foo.BAR = 2 = 0b010` and `Foo.BAZ = 4 = 0b100`.
That allows for easily combining flags e.g. `Foo.BAR | Foo.BAZ = 2 | 4 = 0b010 | 0b100 = 0b110 = 6`.

Now combining `Foo.None` and `Foo.BAR` the same way you end up with `3` or its binary representation of `0b011` which is the representation of having the bits for both `Foo.NONE` and `Foo.BAR` set.

How to solve the issue?

The "trick" is to think about the bit representation of what is being expressed.
Since individual bits being set correspond to enum members, not having any bits set should correspond to the `NONE` member i.e.:

```py
import enum

class Foo(enum.Flag):
    NONE = 0
    BAR = enum.auto()
    BAZ = enum.auto()
```

Users of your library can easily specify "no flags" using `Foo.NONE` this way while combining it with "actual" flags now behaves as expected:

```
>>> foo = Foo.NONE
>>> foo
<Foo.NONE: 0>
>>> foo |= Foo.BAR
>>> foo
<Foo.BAR: 1>
```

Comment: Yes, but you get a small caveat: `list(Foo)` will render `[Foo.NONE, Foo.BAR, Foo.BAZ]`, and this might not be the expected behavior.